# JWT token verification fails in C

Tags: c, jwt, cryptography, padding, digital-signature

I am trying to verify JWT token which has PS384 algorithm in its header. I am trying using [this library](https://github.com/xmidt-org/cjwt). [This](https://github.com/xmidt-org/cjwt/tree/main/examples/basic) provides some sample applications also including [RS256 algorithm](https://github.com/xmidt-org/cjwt/blob/main/examples/basic/rs_example.c).

and it is mentioned that PS is almost same as RS. So I tried the same application with my PS384 algorithm used JWT token. but hitting into below error from function EVP_DigestVerifyFinal(md_ctx, in->sig.data, in->sig.len) in jws_evp_openssl.c

Error code : 67625094
Error str : error:0407E086:rsa routines:RSA_verify_PKCS1_PSS_mgf1:last octet invalid

Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: complete data about this issue available here.  https://github.com/xmidt-org/cjwt/blob/main/examples/basic/rs_example.c